# How to prevent Jest from seeing a function being called or implement function differently?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a script with a function being called at the end. I want to prevent `doSomething()` from throwing an error in the jest tests.

calculator.js

```js
const add = (a, b) => { return a + b; }

function doSomething(){
    throw Error('dang I messed you up')
}

doSomething(); //  this gets call in Jest test everytime

module.exports = {
    add,
    somethingElse
}
```

In test file, I want to prevent `doSomething()` from being called:

```js
const Calc = require('../calculator.js');
const { add, doSomething } = Calc;

// prevent doSomething() from being called 
doSomething.mockImplementation(() => console.log('so much nope'));
// or
jest.spyOn(Calc, 'doSomething').mockImplementation(() => console.log('so much nope'));

test('Adding two numbers', async () => {
    expect(add(5, 5)).toStrictEqual(10)
})
```

Jest isn't changing the implementation, but instead still shows the error.

[image: jest seeing error from doSomething]

Comment: You can't. The module has to be executed to import it, and that error is in a function invocation at the top level. If you don't want that to happen, _don't call functions at the top level_.